# File manipulation using Python

Tags: python

I recently started working in a lab that generate a lot of data. I need to manipulate files very often for various needs. I have learnt awk programming but it seems not enough for my work. I know python but not to that extent where I can comfortably work on files. Could anyone please suggest to me any book or online tutorial where I can find exclusively the use of Python on files. most of the python books do not dwell intensively on this subject.
thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I'd like to inform you that StackOverflow is not the place to ask for recommendations, as these tend to bring about opinionated answers. I felt it necessary to raise a flag as such. StackOverflow is designed primarily for answering questions that come up in the actual coding process. However, I will mention that an objectively good jumping off point is the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for file I/O Python. Thanks.

Comment: Or [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) version of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find these materials are helpful:

http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html
http://opentechschool.github.io/python-data-intro/core/text-files.html

For data manipulation, you may need to improve your skills in string processing, regular expression operations, data structures,....
You can attend this course:
https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-python-data-science-microsoft-dat208x-0

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend familiarizing yourself with **the [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [sys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) standard libraries**. Here is a [comprehensive tutorial](http://www.thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/module_os.html) that covers both libraries and other necessary aspects of file management in Python.